# How to fix "coordinatorLayoutStyle" issue with Android Studio starting project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Just installed and started my new android project on Windows 10 and i got this render issue: "Failed to find style '`coordinatorLayoutStyle`' in current theme"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxe5L.jpg

Already tried :

- Reinstalling Android Studio and JDK
- Refreshing the project
- Cleaning and rebuilding the project
- Installing all the APIs
- tried adding "@style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout"
  to the `styles.xml` (which created even more problems)

Anymore ideas ?

I also have these small problems with android -

1) The resource `@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` is marked as private in `com.android.support:design`

2) Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?

3) The following classes could not be instantiated:

```
- android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshoot of your android Studio

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/lumm8C0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this line above your main java code:

```
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
```